# I'm trying to run groovy script inside java

Tags: java, groovy, runtime, state

I have a parsed HTML file that has a  tag with a groovy script inside.
I have the groovy script inside a string and I have to execute it during runtime and keep the state so I can use it later.

Anyone has any clue how to:

1. Run the groovy script inside java
2. Keep the state for further use.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `groovy.util.Eval` class is probably the simplest way to execute Groovy dynamically at runtime. Given below is an example:

```
import groovy.util.Eval;

public class Goovy123 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Eval.me("33*3"));//99
        System.out.println(Eval.me("'foo'.toUpperCase()"));//FOO
    }
}
```

I have used the following maven dependency in my project for the required library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.8</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

**Update:**

I am posting this update to add the example for the state which was missing in my original answer. Using the `groovy.lang.Binding` class, you can keep the state in a variable and use it later in your program. Given below is an example:

```
import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;
import groovy.util.Eval;

public class Goovy123 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        String foo="foo";   
        binding.setVariable("foo", foo);
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
        System.out.println("Original state: "+binding.getVariable("foo"));
        shell.evaluate("foo=foo.toUpperCase();");
        System.out.println("Changed state: "+binding.getVariable("foo"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it be possible to keep the state with Eval? 
Because I have scripts like this
`import com.teste.Bike
def id = request.getParameter("id")
bike = Bike.lookup(id)`

and later i have to use methods from Bike class.